# Pyowm visual studio 'connection' error

Tags: python, pyowm

```
import pyowm

owm = pyowm.OWM('##############',{'language': 'ru'})
mgr = owm.weather_manager()
observation = mgr.weather_at_place('Брянск')
w = observation.weather()
print(w)
```

Описания ошибки в интернете не нашел.
Надеюсь на вашу помощь
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Сообщение = 'connection'
  Источник = C:\Users\croco\source\repos\Pybot\Pybot\Pybot.py
  Трассировка стека:
  File "C:\Users\croco\source\repos\Pybot\Pybot\Pybot.py", line 6, in <module>
    observation = mgr.weather_at_place('Брянск')